# How can I link a lib file library with CMake in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, logitech-led-illumination-sdk

I would like to add the Logitech SDK to configure the LEDs on my keyboard.

I'm new to C++ and I've looked at some tutorials but nothing worked. The library I need to add has a . lib extension.
With my current configuration, Clion doesn't detect any error and CMake compiles fine. However, when I run main.cpp I get the error:

`` CMakeFiles\ambiLight.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main': C:/.../ambiLight/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `LogiLedInit()' ``
How can I fix this problem?

Here is my configuration:
Tree files:

```
ambiLight
   |
   |--- CMakeLists.txt
   |--- main.cpp
   |--- LogitechLEDLib.h
   |--- LogitechLEDLib.lib
   |--- LogitechLedEnginesWrapper.dll
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(ambiLight)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(ambiLight main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ambiLight LogitechLEDLib.lib)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LogitechLEDLib.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    LogiLedInit();
    return 0;
}
```

CMake output:

```
C:\...\CLion\ch-0\211.7142.21\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\...\ambiLight
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/.../ambiLight/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Main.cpp output:

```
====================[ Build | ambiLight | Debug ]===============================
C:\...\CLion\ch-0\211.7142.21\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\...\ambiLight\cmake-build-debug --target ambiLight -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target ambiLight
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ambiLight.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable ambiLight.exe
CMakeFiles\ambiLight.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/.../ambiLight/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `LogiLedInit()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\ambiLight.dir\build.make:105: ambiLight.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/ambiLight.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: CMakeFiles/ambiLight.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: ambiLight] Error 2
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Excuse me everyone, you are right @tadman. I edited my post to add all the information in texts.

Comment: That doesn't look like "compiles fine", that looks like a link-stage failure. `ld` is the linker and it's having trouble finding the library with that `LogiLedInit()` function in it. You may need to add that library's location to your library path. The default search path does not include your source directory. Your directives might cover that, but you need to be sure.

Comment: @tadman How can I add a path to this library?

Comment: Can you get the actual `ld` command executed? I'm not familiar with CMake notation, but that should translate into an `ld` argument including the library with the correct path.

Comment: The library is probably meant for, and built by, the Microsoft compiler. You cannot use it with gcc.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Does this mean I have to use Visual Studio?

Comment: This is one option. I think you can set up CLion and CMake to use the Microsoft compiler, though I have never done that. The third option would be to build the Logitech SDK yourself with the gcc toolchain, but I don't think the source is available. There is an independent open source version for Linux, but porting it to Windows would require some skills and time.